# certbot on docker doesn't create multiple live folders for subdomains

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, certificate, certbot

I run a couple docker containers, in this case a webserver running `nginx:alpine` and the default `certbox/certbox` image.
On the Nginx container, i run 2 server parts for subdomains with a static website. The main domain runs on a different VPS, so i made specific A records for these two subdomains.

This is my `nginx.conf`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/website1;
  index index.html;

  server_name website1.example.com;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    root /var/www/website1;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/website2;
  index index.html;

  server_name website2.example.com;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    root /var/www/website2;
  }
}
```

As expected, i can see both websites working on the subdomains.

But when i try running the certbot on both sites, only one folder (the one of the first subdomain) is created!

This is the docker compose file i use for this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - website1:/var/www/website1
      - website2:/var/www/website2
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - website1:/var/www/website1
      - website2:/var/www/website2
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    command: certonly --email my.name@example.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging --webroot -w /var/www/website1 -d website1.example.com -w /var/www/website2 -d website2.example.com

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  website1:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/user/html/website1/
      o: bind
  website2:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/user/html/website2/
      o: bind

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The certbot container runs fine, exits with `(0)` and when i go and look in the webserver container:
`sudo docker-compose exec webserver ls -la /etc/letsencrypt/live` i get the following:

```
total 16
drwx------    3 root     root          4096 Feb  7 20:05 .
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root          4096 Feb  8 12:19 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           740 Feb  7 20:05 README
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Feb  7 20:05 website1.example.com
```

So the second subdomain isn't created.

I also tried to add two different certonly runs by changing my `docker-compose.yml` command to:

```
command: >
      sh -c "certonly --email my.name@example.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging --webroot -w /var/www/website1 -d website1.example.com
          && certonly --email my.name@example.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging --webroot -w /var/www/website2 -d website2.example.com"
```

But this results in an error:
`certbot: error: File not found: certonly --email my.name@example.com --a...`

How can i make certbot create certificates for both subdomains? Or how can i use multiple commands in my `docker-compose.yml` file without having it return an error?

Comment: I believe that the certificate that certbot generated can be used on all domains specified by the -d command when running certbot though docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

For image: `certbot/certbot` - entrypoint is certbot so you can only include one line certbot arguments.
If you want to generate two folders / use `--cert-name` before you point `-w -d` for 2nd domain/website2.

```
command: certonly --email my.name@example.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging --webroot --cert-name website1.example.com -w /var/www/website1 -d website1.example.com --cert-name website2.example.com -w /var/www/website2 -d website2.example.com
```

Comment: unrecognized arguments:  --cert-name