# Generating Let's Encrypt certificate for multiple domains on Docker Compose with Certbot

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, certbot

I have two domains:

```
- domain1.com
- domain2.com
```

I want to generate the `Let's Encrypt` certificates by separate for they 2 (including the `www.` domain on each of them), i.e.:

```
Cert 1: domain1.com, www.domain1.com
Cert 2: domain2.com, www.domain2.com
```

For that I tried with the: `docker-compose.yml` below:

```
version: '3'

services:

  webserver:
    image: domain1-com-webserver
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.webserver
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot-domain1-com:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot-domain1-com
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    profiles: ["with-le"]
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email info@domain1.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --dry-run -d domain1.com -d www.domain1.com

  certbot-domain2-com:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot-domain2-com
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    profiles: ["with-le"]
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email info@domain2.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --dry-run --force-renewal -d domain2.com -d www.domain2.com

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

But when running:

```
$ docker-compose --profile with-le up -d
```

I got the following logs:

```
$ docker logs certbot-domain1-com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Account registered.
Simulating a certificate request for domain1.com and www.domain1.com
The dry run was successful.

$ docker logs certbot-domain2-com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Another instance of Certbot is already running.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

Notice that the first Dry-Run certificate succeeded, but the second one failed.

Any ways on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can issue multiple certificates using just one container. You don't need multiple containers. Like this:

```
  certbot-domain1-com:
image: certbot/certbot
container_name: certbot-domain1-com
volumes:
  - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
  - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
  - web-root:/var/www/html
depends_on:
  - webserver
profiles: ["with-le"]
command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email info@domain1.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --dry-run --cert-name domain1.com -w /etc/letsencrypt -d domain1.com --cert-name domain2.com -w /etc/letsencrypt -d domain2.com
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128216/certbot-on-docker-doesnt-create-multiple-live-folders-for-subdomains)